# Modifying URLs on a Rest Server in Delphi

Tags: delphi, rest, delphi-xe

I've written a REST server in Delphi XE (using the wizard) and I want to change the URLs a bit so that instead of having
http://192.168.1.84:8080/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods1/GetListings
I get something that looks more like http://192.168.1.84:8080/GetListings

Is there a nice easy of doing this?

Comment: this is usually done in the web server configuration, in Apache using URL redirect entries in the .htaccess file

Comment: yes, also available on IIS (at least 7 maybe 6) if you install the MS supplied URLRewrite module.

Comment: @mjustin & @Marjan: It's a standalone server so it's not running under apache or IIS.  This question is pretty much restricted to people who know about some of the web capabilities of Delphi.

Comment: any luck with rewriting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The naming convention is (Delphi XE3):

http://my.site.com/datasnap/rest/URIClassName/URIMethodName[/inputParameter]

You can easily change the "datasnap" and "rest" part of the URL in the TDSHTTPWebDispatcher component properties. You can change the Class Name and Method Name of the URL by simply changing the name of your class and method. However, you still have to have 4 components to the URL, so for example it could be:

http://my.site.com/api/v1/People/Listing

See here:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/REST#Customizing_the_URL_for_REST_requests

Comment: You can remove the DataSnap part of the properties if you use TDSHTTPService (XE5+)

Answer (score 3):

You could put IIS or Apache in between to accomplish this, and indeed rewrite the URL to point to your service the way you like.

That provides some more advantages anyway (security and scalability mostly). For example, you can create a fail-safe setup with double servers, or you can create multiple machines with your service, and have your web server do the load balancing for example.

You'll get extra logging capabilities, and if you easily want to serve other web content it's easy to have a full fledged web server anyway.

Comment: +1 it has so many advantages I can not imagine any production servers not using it, for example support for HTTPS/SSL without touching the Delphi side

Answer (score 0):

[URL rewriting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine) is usually done in the web server configuration, in Apache using [entries in the .htaccess file](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)

Comment: It's a standalone server so it doesn't use Apache or IIS.